# Creating CSV of information extracted from filenames in a given format

Tags: perl, shell

I have a little script that lists paths to all files in a directory and all subdirectories and parses each path on the list with regex in Perl.

```
#!/bin/sh
find * -type f | while read j; do
echo $j | perl -n -e '/\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d+).*-([a-zA-Z]+)(?:_(\d{1}))?/ && print "\"0\";\"$1$2$3\";\"$4\";\"$5\";$fl\""' >> bss.csv
echo | readlink -f -n "$j" >>bss.csv
echo \">>bss.csv
done
```

Output:

```
"0";"13957";"4121113";"2";"/home/root/dir1/bss/164146/13/95/7___/000240216___Abc-4121113_2.jpg"
```

I am using the `readlink` from GNU coreutils: `-n` suppresses newline at the end, `-f` performs canonicalization by recursively following symlinks on the path.

Problem is, when input string did not pass regex I have only line with file path.

How can I add condition to check if regex passed - show path, else - no.
I broke my brain with various combinations, but didn't find any that work properly.

Comment: When regex doesn't match your line is filtered.

Comment: @Сухой27 right, but `echo | readlink -f -n "$j" >>bss.csv` runs in any case.

Comment: You've tagged your question `[bash]`, but your script starts with `#!/bin/sh`.  Are you looking for bash-only solutions, or are you open to solutions that are more portable?

Comment: @SergiiRechmp - your script may break if filenames contain special characters - newlines or control characters.  Is that okay?

Comment: It probably would be better if you just do it with `Perl` anyway. Forget using `/bin/sh` to wrap things around.

Comment: @konsolebox - yes, either all-Perl or all-shell.  Mixed scripts like this are always so awkward.

Comment: @SergiiRechmp - as the first comment here hinted, your regex doesn't match the filename you've included in your example.  Can you please clearly express the translation that you want to do between old filename and CSV?

Comment: Use generic quotes: `qq()` in Perl one-liners to avoid having to escape all those "s in the future. You can also use a different delimiter for regexes to avoid having to escape all those forward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description of solution

In Perl, use `if (/…/) {…} else {…}` instead of `/…/ && …`. Thus you can execute print if match is successful and some other code otherwise.

If this is not the problem and you only want to get rid of the `readlink` output and closing quote, you can call `readlink` from Perl using backticks.

## Resulting code

I turned everything into a single Perl program, used `File::Find` instead of `find` command, assumed `$fl` at the end of `print` in Perl is a relict (ignored it) and used `Cwd::realpath()` to find canonical path of the file instead of `readlink -f` from GNU coreutils. If you still want to use `readlink -f`, feel free to change `Cwd::realpath($_)` to `` `readlink -f '$_'` `` (including the backticks!), but then it will not work for filenames containing a single-quote.

You should call this script as `./script-name starting-directory > bss.csv`. If you put it in the directory you are examining, the output would contain it too, along with the `bss.csv`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage: ./$0 [<starting-directory>...]
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;
no warnings 'File::Find';

sub handleFile() {
    return if not -f;
    if ($File::Find::name =~ /\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d+).*-([a-zA-Z]+)(?:_(\d{1}))?/) {
        local $, = ';', $\ = "\n";
        print map "\"$_\"", 0, $1.$2.$3, $4, $5, Cwd::realpath($_);
    } else {
        print STDERR "File $File::Find::name did not match\n";
    }
}

find(\&handleFile, @ARGV ? @ARGV : '.');
```

For reference I also enclose polished version of the original program. It is calling `readlink` from Perl as I suggested above and really utilizes the `-n` option of Perl, avoiding the `while read` loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f | perl -n -e 'm{/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d+).*-([a-zA-Z]+)(?:_(\d{1}))?} && print qq{"0";"$1$2$3";"$4";"$5";"`readlink -f -n '\''$_'\''`"}' > bss.csv
```

## Other remarks to the original code

- The `echo |` before the `readlink` does nothing and should be removed. Readlink does not read its stdin.
- Where does `$fl` at the end of `print` in Perl come from? I assume it is a relict.
- Use of generic quotes like `qq{}` and thoughtful use of delimiters (e.g. in regex matching and other quote-like operators) can save you from quoting hell. *I already used this tip above: `/…/` → `m{…}` and `"…"` → `qq{…}`. Thx, [Slade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2884483/slade)!* See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) manpage for more info.

Comment: I did not touch the regex. It is a relatively self-contained part of the code and is not the main issue nor the issue being asked about. If you want to fix it, see [ghoti’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24635407/2157640).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to capture the following parts of the filename:

```
/home/root/dir1/bss/164146/13/95/7___/000240216___Abc-4121113_2.jpg
                           ~~ ~~ ~                ~~~ ~~~~~~~ ~
                           1  2  3                4   5       6
```

But your perl regex doesn't do that.  Let's break it apart for better understanding.

```
/\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d+).*-([a-zA-Z]+)(?:_(\d{1}))?/
```

Sliced into pieces, this would be...

- `\/(\d{2})` - a slash then two digits (with the digits captured)
- `\/(\d{2})` - another slash and two digits
- `\/(\d)` - one more slash and any number of digits
- `.*-` - any run of characters until the final hyphen in the input string
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - one or more alpha characters
- `(?:_(\d{1}))?` - nonsensical (I think) construct matching an optional single digit that won't be captured (because it's inside a `(?:...)`)

If you step through your filename, you'll see that there is nothing here to handle the second last string of digits.

I'd do this using simpler tools.  Sed, for example:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ s="/home/root/dir1/bss/164146/13/95/7___/000240216___Abc-4121113_2.jpg"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "$s" | sed -rne 's/.*/"&"/;h;s:.*/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)[^[a-zA-Z]]*[^-]+-([0-9]+)(_([0-9]+))?.*:"0";"\1\2\3";"\4";"\6":;G;s/\n/;/;p'
"0";"13957";"4121113";"2";"/home/root/dir1/bss/164146/13/95/7___/000240216___Abc-4121113_2.jpg"
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

I'll break up the sed script for easier reading:

- `s/.*/"&"/;` - Put quotes around the filename.
- `h;` - Store the filename in Sed's "hold" space, for future use...
- `s:` - Start the big substitution...

  - `.*/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)[^[a-zA-Z]]*[^-]+-([0-9]+)(_([0-9]+))?.*` - This is the pattern we want to match for substitution. Similar to what you did in Perl, obviously, but using ERE instead of PCRE.
  - `:"0";"\1\2\3";"\4";"\6":;` - The replacement pattern, with `\n` being replaced by the bracketed elements of the RE.  Note that `\5` is skipped in the replace string, as that subexpression is only being used for the match.
- `G;` - Append the "hold" space to the pattern space
- `s/\n/;/;` - and remove the newline between them.
- `p` - Print the result.

Note that this solution, as is, assumes that all input lines match the pattern you're looking for.  If that's not the case, then you may get unpredictable output, and should put some pattern matching into the script.

Comment: Perl does not use PCRE. PCRE is a library, whose full name is Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions. Perl’s regular expressions are called perlre. See [tag:pcre] tag wiki.

Comment: That's the nice thing about standards -- there are so many to choose from.  Thanks for the reminder about PCRE.  Out of curiosity, would the OP's perlre-parsed regex have been interpreted the same way by PCRE?

Comment: Only standard regex flavors are POSIX basic and POSIX extended, AFAIK. Not sure e.g. about standardization of Java, regexes in C++, … But that is just another level of nitpicking, forget that. PCRE aims to be mostly compatible with perlre, this regex does not run in any of the corner cases. See [PCRE @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions#Differences_from_Perl) and [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php) for differences between the two regex flavors.

Comment: @Palec, even "standard" BRE and ERE are incompletely or inaccurately implemented in many cases.  Even if ERE support is *claimed*, it isn't always completely there.  It's always important to know what interpreter you're using.